# What should the tag for Mahouka Koukou no Rettousei / The Irregular at Magic High School be?

Tags: discussion, tags

So there's [*The Irregular at Magic High School*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Irregular_at_Magic_High_School), right? I just asked [a question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/does-that-weird-translucent-thing-the-girls-wear-serve-any-specific-purpose) about it and provisionally tagged it with [mahouka-koukou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahouka-koukou). Should we stick with this, or pick a different tag?

We can't use `irregular-at-magic-high-school` (30 chars) or `mahouka-koukou-no-rettousei` (27 chars). We could go with a shortening of the Japanese title, like:

- `mahouka`
- `mahouka-koukou` (what I picked)
- `mahouka-koukou-rettousei`

Or, we could shorten the English title, but I'm not sure that there is any shortening that makes good sense (unless we could just do `magic-high-school`, but that omits the important word "irregular").

Comment: I am happy with any really, but I definitely wouldn't go for one too long. I might go for the third dotpoint though as it is in my opinion it seems more "complete".

Answer (score 2):

I definitely think that mahouka-koukou, so as it is now. Is the best choice. The series has several different manga simultaneously airing, and this title covers all of them

[image]